# create personal short cut for print option javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a java script which helps me to create a personal short cut.

we all know what CTRL+P refers to PRINT. but i want to change it to **Ctrl+Shift+W**. i mean when user press "Ctrl+Shift+W"" (opening my webpage), the print box should open...

An example code

```
shortcut.add("Ctrl+Shift+W",function() {
    alert("Hi there!");
});
```

check this at http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/ for live Evaluation

kindle please update this code, so that when user enter Ctrl+Shift+W, print box should open.

thank you :)

Comment: Try http://rent-acoder.com

Comment: Because Ctrl-P is too easy? Did you try using  `window.print()`;

Comment: @epascarello sorry, no :D am just asked this to learn. :) kindle please help me :)

Comment: so put the window.print() in place of the alert() TADA, print is called.

Comment: Why do you want to change default functionality? Just to make it less user friendly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at mouse trap if you want to do keyboard shortcuts:
http://craig.is/killing/mice

```
Mousetrap.bind('command+shift+w', function(e) {
   window.print();
});
```